# Path to the product in the list mode in magento

Tags: php, magento

hello guys can please anyone tell me the path to the product page in list mode in Magento.In grid mode its showing good,but when i click to list mode,i wanna remove some items from it, so please help me with the path

Comment: Did my answer help you any further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the regular product list (and grid) is situated here:

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml
```

But ofcourse, this could vary depending on the template you are using. Most templates keep the same folder structure, so it should be somewhere along these lines:

```
app/design/frontend/TEMPLATENAME/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check file name by enabling file path hint in magento. For enable file path hint you need to follow the steps:

1. log into the magento back-end admin
2. Go to System -> Configuration in the main menu
3. Go to Developer on the bottom left under ADVANCED
4. Switch to the store view on the top left to your current website or store view.
5. Under the Debug tab of the same Developer config page you will see a new option appear  that will allow you to turn on template path hints.
6. then click on save button

Refresh your product page.